# How to align source code section in both Org-src-edit-code, Org-mode, and exported PDF file?

Tags: org-mode, latex, regular-expressions, tabs, align

[image]

How to configure emacs such that code (in this case `:which-key`) is aligned in both `org-edit-src-code` `org-mode` and exported `PDF`?

I'm guessing this is somewhat related to `tabs` getting different amount of `spaces` in each modes. But I can't configure all three 3 at once. Followings are my ideas, but I can't implement them in elisp:

- Never use `tabs`, just always use `spaces`
- Would changing `align-regexp` to use 4 spaces instead of `\t` solve all three at once?
- Or use `untabify` on `org-edit-src-code` exit hook?

---

**Update**: As NickD suggested I'm providing the Org file. Directly copy-pasting here will mess up the tab & spaces. So I uploaded here in [G-drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dcu4SsNZkIQQAZLv-3ieSezCdahberIy/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: It would help if you posted the Org mode file as *text* (not as an image). We could then try it out without having to type the whole thing *ab initio*. That will likely help get you an answer sooner too.

Comment: @NickD, Sorry, I included the file above

Comment: Your hunch is correct I think and the only solution I can think of is to eliminate tabs altogether, but that makes the initial alignment trickier. Personally, I don't use tabs at all and I align things manually in most cases, although there is some help - e.g. in this case `M-x align-regexp RET :.* RET` would align the colons, but if there are more colons on each line, the regexp would probably have to be more complicated; you'd probably need groups, which is why I go full manual in such cases.

Comment: I think we can redefine `align-regexp` as combination of `align-regexp` + `untabify`.

Comment: And then, eleminate other tabs. How do you eliminate tabs yourself?

Comment: I do `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` in my init file. That does not prevent *some* major modes to use TAB for indentation (e.g. C mode and Makefile mode) but most major modes don't override it (e.g. python mode, org mode, elisp mode) and that works fine for me. For files with tabs in them already, `untabify` is the only solution I know.